# ica file not directing to citrix receiver

Tags: citrix

I am using Windows 10 and I am trying to open a pop-up-window of an ica file which should be directed to Citrix receiver application already installed on my laptop. But nothing opens up even after waiting or clicking on that file again and again. Is there a way where I can redirect that pop-up to open Citrix receiver?Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes happens due to broken file associations. You can point it to (C:\Program Files(x86)\Citrix\Reciever\wfcrun32.exe) or if you have installed receiver to a custom location then that path, finally pointing to wfcrun32.exe